# How do the following new (2013) ECC curves compare in security or efficiency?

Tags: elliptic-curves, performance

I read about the following ["safe" ECC curves](http://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) and notably, secp256 and all the NIST curves are marked as "unsafe" when compared to more modern curves.

I need a curve for signing or encryption, (or both) but not sure how to choose from the following:

- M-221
- E-222
- Curve1174
- Curve25519
- E-382
- M-383
- Curve383187
- Curve41417
- Ed448-Goldilocks
- M-511
- E-521

Questions:

1. Are there performance, size, or power efficiencies from one curve to another?
2. Perhaps more important, are there security improvements over a given curve?

Comment: M511 and E521 will be the most secure, I prefer M511, which gives 170 bits of security against post-quantum attacks (that as of yet dont exist) and is easily and securely implementable. 384 (383) bits is my min requirement.

Comment: "post-quantum"?

Comment: The larger the curves the slower (but stronger) they are.

Comment: post-quantum = in a world where powerful quantum computers not only exist but are common and efficient, and can be used to solve the discrete logarithm problem and/or factor large integers

Comment: Quantum computers can compute d.logs. on all of these curves. "Post-quantum" they have no security.

Comment: You can compute them now, but the workload is insane. With quantum algorithms, the workload is smaller, but not nearly as small as with RSA, which is why there is such a hard push to elliptic curves.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301141

Comment: Sorry to say so, but from my point of view *…“**most** secure or efficient…”* is **primarily opinion based**. Same goes for sub-questions asking *“…which curve is **ideal**…”*. And even when I would ignore all the primarily opinion based stuff, questions that go *“If a new alt-coin (Bitcoin) were created today…”* are nothing else than “what if” questions, which are [off-topic according to our help center](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @e-sushi I don't think "what properties would make a curve ideal" is a bad question per se, just for the sake of defining "ideal", but I agree with the close vote.

Comment: If you refrain from closing I'll make the requested modifications later tonight.

Comment: I don't think questions 1 or 2 are opinion based. 3 is, but it can be removed.

Comment: The meaning of "post-quantum" should probably be updated, now that the quantum architecture utterly failed in testing.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there performance, size, or power efficiencies from one curve to another?

The larger the curve, the larger the keys and signatures, and likely the slower the computations. There are exceptions to the last one – curve parameters do affect how efficiently they can be implemented, so some curves with good parameters can be faster than slightly smaller curves.

> Perhaps more important, are there security improvements over a given curve?

All of them should be safe, but the larger curves have more security margin.

> If a new alt-coin (Bitcoin) were created today, which curve is ideal?

Since signatures and public keys appear in the blockchain, having them be small would be great. Having signature verifications take little time would also be good, since that's time wasted.

Curve25519 has 256-bit keys and 512-bit signatures, and is known to have a fast implementation (Ed25519 for signatures). Especially if it gets standardized, it would be a decent choice.

Unless there's some kind of a breakthrough, 256 bit curves with 128-bit security should be enough until/unless quantum computers break ECC. For a post-quantum altcoin, you could use e.g. hash signatures, but that would expand the blockchain quite a bit.